# Why view modifier can't take in immutable variable?

Tags: swift, swiftui, viewmodifier

I made a button modifier, the background colour should change according to if it has been clicked or not. But I get complaint that the input parameter of viewModifier is immutable.

I got error on **btnBkColor** of

```
.modifier(ActionButtonType(bkColor: btnBkColor))
```

The error msg:

> Cannot use mutating getter on immutable value: 'self' is immutable

Here are my simplified code:

```
struct MyView: View {
@State private var cond = false
private lazy var btnBkColor: Color = cond ? Color.orange : Color.green
var body: some View {
              Button(action: { cond.toggle() }, label: {
              Text(cond ? "A" : "B")
  })
  .modifier(ActionButtonType(bkColor: btnBkColor))
}
}
```

Modifier:

```
struct ActionButtonType: ViewModifier {
    let bkColor: Color
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .background(bkColor)
    }
}
```

*I only get but not set btnBkColor inside ViewModifier, I don't understand why can't the input parameter be immutable?*

What I have tried but not help:

- change let to var
- add @State in front of btnBkColor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use computed property. You can not use the self variable directly to the other variable.

```
struct MyView: View {
    @State private var cond = false
    
    private var btnBkColor: Color {
        cond ? Color.orange : Color.green
    } // <--Here
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: { cond.toggle() }, label: {
            Text(cond ? "A" : "B")
        })
        .modifier(ActionButtonType(bkColor: btnBkColor))
    }
}
```

Comment: With your 2nd solution, `btnBkColor` won't be updated when `cond` is updated.

Comment: @DávidPásztor. Oh yes.

Comment: Hi, it's cool how you declare btnBkColor, I have tried

private var btnBkColor: Color = (cond ? Color.orange : Color.green)

but get the error of "Cannot use instance member 'cond' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"

it works with your syntax !

Comment: Use curly bracket and remove equal to sign : ``` private var btnBkColor: Color {
        cond ? Color.orange : Color.green
    }```

Answer (score 2):

The simplest case, and most often used in SwiftUI code, is to use state dependency inline of modifier (this will also be animatable when/if needed)

```
struct MyView: View {
  @State private var cond = false

  var body: some View {
      Button(action: { cond.toggle() }, label: {
         Text(cond ? "A" : "B")
      })
      .modifier(ActionButtonType(bkColor: cond ? Color.orange : Color.green))
  }
}
```